# AWS Lex Chatbot - Send user a follow up message if no response detected

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

Is there a way to have an AWS Lex chatbot send a follow-up response to a user if the user has not replied after a certain amount of time?

Answer (score 0):

Lex responds to direct inputs. Lex, by itself, will not prompt the user to engage if the user does not respond within a specified timeframe.
That is custom logic that you would need to implement outside of Lex.

Comment: Thank you @Reegz for the response here... would custom logic you are mentioning would have to take place in a lambda function?

Comment: Yes, you could possibly use a lambda function. Ideally, you'll need to keep a record of the time the last message was sent/received. Using CloudWatch Events you can create a trigger to execute a lambda at a set interval (say, every 2 minutes). Your lambda would need to decide whether to prompt the user and then fire off that event to the end-user.